# Не могу понять как заполнять структуру?

Tags: c++, c, массивы, struct, информатика

Создать массив объединений, содержащих поля unsigned int,
массив unsigned short из двух элементов и массив unsigned char из четырех
элементов. Заполнить его значениями от 1 до 2^31. Вывести получившиеся
последовательности слов и байтов. Проанализировать результат. Реализовать
побайтное сложение чисел.

Comment: Ну т.е. убедиться, что strict aliasing - ерунда :) `union Type { unsigned int A; unsigned short B[2]; unsigned char C[4]; }` - примерно в эту сторону смотрите...

Comment: говорят, что в си это все таки законно. А вот в плюса - да, можно получить кучу фана. Можно, но пока типы "простые старые" проблем не видел ни разу.

Comment: Для POD-типов в C++ всё в порядке. Для не POD нужно соблюдать специальные правила (введено в каком-то свежем стандарте).

Comment: меня тревожит другое - "Заполнить его значениями от 1 до 2^31", я так понимаю в цикле. а потом вывести.... вывести 4+ миллиарда значений...

Comment: @KoVadim, поскольку не сказано *всеми*, то не вижу особых проблем.

Comment: @KoVadim - "вывести 4+ миллиарда значений"
- На самом деле - всего 5 значений: одно int, два short и четыре char. Этого вполне достаточно, что бы понять суть union.

Comment: ок, мое значение для int 2004318071. Поможет?:)